# Haskell SDL2 accessing GLContext Ptr

Tags: haskell, sdl

I am trying to access the `Ptr` value in a `GLContext` provided by SDL2 library. Here is the function to get a `GLContext`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-2.5.0.0/docs/SDL-Video-OpenGL.html#v:glCreateContext

How do I get access to the `Ptr` inside?

```
import qualified SDL                as SDL
import qualified SDL.Internal.Types as SDL

main :: IO ()
main = do
  SDL.initializeAll
  window @ (SDL.Window wp) <- SDL.createWindow "My SDL Application" SDL.defaultWindow
  context @ (SDL.GLContext gl) <- SDL.glCreateContext window
  putStrLn $ show wp
```

But the error I get is:

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘SDL.GLContext’
Neither ‘SDL’ nor ‘SDL.Internal.Types’ exports ‘
   |
15 |   context @ (SDL.GLContext gl) <- SDL.glCreateContext window
```

The constructor appears to be exported. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Semantically SDL_GLContext is not a pointer type. I have no idea about haskell at all though, or what `@` notation means, but can't you e.g. `ctx <- SDL.glCreateContext window`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. I can use the [Raw.Video](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-2.5.0.0/docs/SDL-Raw-Video.html#v:glCreateContext) module which has a `glCreateContext` function that returns the type I need.